# response.json() rendering old variable

Tags: json, node.js, express

I have a simple JSON API which for some reason is rendering another value than what `console.log` is reporting that the value has.

My route:

```
app.get('/dateRecords', function(request, response, next) {
    console.log('/dateRecords', api.dateRecords);
    response.json(api.dateRecords);
});
```

This is my api.js:

```
exports.dateRecords = exports.dateRecords || [];

exports.listData = function(req, res) {
    console.log('listData:', exports.dateRecords);
    return res.json(exports.dateRecords);
};
```

Console output:

```
listData: []
addData: [ '2014-01-22': { requestedInvites: 47 } ]
addData: [ '2014-01-22': { requestedInvites: 47, registrations: 5 } ]
getStatsForDate http://create.gootechnologies.com/api/metrics/ksa8dVWi8sPg41?mode=1&day=20140122
listData: [ '2014-01-22': { requestedInvites: 47, registrations: 5 } ]
addData: [ '2014-01-22': { requestedInvites: 47, registrations: 5 } ]
addData: [ '2014-01-22': { requestedInvites: 47, registrations: 5 } ]
getStatsForDate http://create.gootechnologies.com/api/metrics/ksa8dVWi8sPg41?mode=1&day=20140105
listData: [ '2014-01-22': { requestedInvites: 47, registrations: 5 } ]
addData: [ '2014-01-22': { requestedInvites: 47, registrations: 5 }, '2014-01-05': { requestedInvites: 49 } ]
addData: [ '2014-01-22': { requestedInvites: 47, registrations: 5 }, '2014-01-05': { requestedInvites: 49, registrations: 20 } ]
/dateRecords [ '2014-01-22': { requestedInvites: 47, registrations: 5 }, '2014-01-05': { requestedInvites: 49, registrations: 20 } ]
```

Browser output:

```
[]
```

(i.e. the initial value of `exports.dateRecords`)

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.json` uses `JSON.stringify`. `JSON.stringify` ignores the properties of the array with non-numeric keys.

```
  var a = [1,2,3];

  JSON.stringify(a); // '[1,2,3]'

  a.hi = 4;

  JSON.stringify(a); // '[1,2,3]'
```

Just pass a regular object instead of an array to `res.json`.

Comment: Thanks! Just realized that the same applies to _any_ array embedded in the JSON structure as well.